# Trying to install Popcorn Time 3.10 on Ubuntu 16.04, but getting an error

Tags: gnome, software-installation, shared-library

Hello there when i try to install Popcorn Time 3.10 with this command:

```
./Popcorn-Time
```

i get this error:

```
./Popcorn-Time: error while loading shared libraries: libnw.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
```

ps: those are my files when i extract the Popcorn-Time-0.3.10-Linux-64.tar.xz file:

```
/locales
/node_modules
/src
/minidump_stackwalk
/nacl_helper
/natives_blob.bin
/payload
/Popcorn-Time
```

Comment: try `sudo chmod -R o+rX <extracted_popcorn_dir>`

Comment: i tried it, but im not sure if it is working and what will do. im also noob to ubuntu...

Comment: the try ./Popcorn-Time again

Comment: same error `./Popcorn-Time: error while loading shared libraries: libnw.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory`

Comment: @Arduino_Sentinel I get the same problem, Did you solve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
sudo chmod -R o+rX "/popcorn_dir"
```

worked for me.
Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Try this. Fix permissions on files:

```
cd /opt/Popcorn (or wherever it is) 
chmod -R 555 * (755 if not ok) 
chown -R root:root *
```

“sudo su” to get permissions on your filesystem.

Answer (score 0):

I also had the same error message.

I had the `lib/` directory in the parent directory of the popcorn executable.

Indeed I had messed up the files during the installation.

After moving the `lib/` directory to be in the same directory containing the executable, the error message was gone and the application could run just fine.

So make sure the `lib/` directory is in your Popcorn directory.

Comment: Thank you for your contribution.  **:-)-** Could you [edit] that and expand a little bit as now it's a low quality answer.